# Error using optidef and environ packages with class file of Wiley journal

Tags: optidef

I am trying to submit a journal article to a Wiley Journal, which requires using their document class file which can be found here (AMA-stix.zip):

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/page/journal/10991514/homepage/la_tex_class_file.htm

When compiling my document with optidef I get two errors:

```
Argument of \env@new has an extra }.
```

and

```
Paragraph ended before \env@new was complete.
```

After some digging, it seems that the issue is actually a conflict with the environ package, which optidef relies on:

https://github.com/jeslago/optidef/issues/20

Below is a MWE that highlights the issue using the environ or optidef packages (from the link cited above):

```
\documentclass[AMA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}

\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{BaseMiniwe}[4]{}%

%\usepackage{optidef}

\begin{document}
    This is some text \cite{article01}

\bibliography{wileyNJD-AMA}%

\end{document}
```

I am not sure based on the error what the issue is exactly. Is there a workaround or tweak that can address the issue or is optidef just not an option when working with this document class?